# Is it possible to induce macroglossia (large tongue) as a result of tongue traction or pulling out?

Tags: oral-health, physical-health, tongue

I know that the human tongue is a muscle, and can't be normally pulled to enlarge it. But these two articles:

https://www.hindawi.com/journals/criot/2019/6040354/

https://europepmc.org/article/med/9292140

report such cases. So I'm asking if it's not *entirely impossible* (so, the probability may be like 0.01%, but not zero) *to enlarge tongue* by tissue overgrowth or tongue swelling etc. as a result of *tongue traction* (pulling), and hence cause *self-inflicted macroglossia?*

Comment: Your first link is broken. I found the article anyway, and it simply describes tongue swelling from an injury, not some sort of muscle enlargement. The second link is an abstract only with the full text behind a pay wall, but it appears to probably be similar. Can your tongue swell due to various causes? Yes, of course. So it's not clear what you're actually asking and your motivation for asking makes your question off topic.

Comment: @CareyGregory I edited the question as as it doesn't sound like I'm asking for medical advice - so you might think of reopening it? I also added a few detail and also corrected the broken URL? which I think is a technical issue. Please let me know if it's okay now?

Comment: Your motivations for asking the question are unnecessary and made the question entirely too personal and strictly about you. Just adding a disclaimer denying that it's a request for medical advice doesn't accomplish anything. I've removed that paragraph and will reopen the question.